# What is the punishment for sulking?

Tags: punishment, behavior

How would we be punished for sulking? Will we not be able enter Jannah and/or will be out of Islam?

Definition of the term:

> Sulk:
>
> verb: sulk; 3rd person present: sulks; past tense: sulked; past >participle: sulked; gerund or present participle: sulking
>
> ```
> 1.
> be silent, morose, and bad-tempered out of annoyance or disappointment.
> "he was sulking over the breakup of his band"
> synonyms:   mope, brood, be sullen, have a long face, be in a bad mood, be in a huff, be grumpy, be moody; informalbe down in the dumps
> "Dad was sulking"
> ```
>
> noun: sulk; plural noun: sulks
>
> ```
> 1.
> a period of gloomy and bad-tempered silence stemming from annoyance and resentment.
> "she was in a fit of the sulks"
> synonyms:   (bad) mood, fit of ill humor, fit of pique, pet, huff, (bad) temper;
> ```

Comment: All we know about what we say is maybe here: http://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/49 or here http://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/45 i don't think a punishment is described in more details somewhere!

Comment: @medi-saif Can you give me more details? I still didn't understand it. Will I still be able to enter Jannah if I sulk?

Comment: Well if sulking is your only "sin" why shouldn't that be possible?

Comment: @medi-saif, I have committed a lot of sins, plus, am I thinking wrong when they said that two people will leave Islam if they don't have a peace between them for more than 2 days?

Comment: @HüdaverdiAlperenDemirok one should not disclose his sin in public it is considered a bigger sin in Islam and Mash Allah if you are ashamed and have made tawbah sincerely then you are pure.

Comment: @servant, you indeed pointed out a significant truth that "one should not disclose his sin in public it is considered a bigger sin in Islam ". Actually the best way in such items can be referring to a related person (privately) and asking.. God bless you for pointing such significant point. / It indicates that how much you pay heed to the question from different aspects. Good luck mate.

Comment: @SEYYED___ALIالسید____علی JazakAllah brother,May Allah Swt give all of us proper understanding and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

There could be some points which you ought to pay heed to, among:

- Every sin has its specific punishment and as much as I know, Allah
  has not mentioned the punishment of all of them or at least most of
  them. On the other hand, on the whole, Allah has named them as the
  means of going to the hell.
- Secondly, as @servant mentioned in his comment

> Mash Allah if you are ashamed and have made tawbah sincerely then you
>   are pure.

Then as Allah said, He will forgive us in case of real repentance. Therefore you'll be pure (at least from this sin) if you do Tawbah (repent).